# android how to call methods with POJO on server

Tags: android, rest, web-services, http, soap

On server (java)

```
public class DbAccessor {

   public Employee getEmployee(Long id) {
      // fetch from database
   }

   public List<Employee> getEmployees(Criteria criteria) {
      // fetch from database
   }

   public void createEmployee(Employee e) {
      // persist
   }
}
```

Employee and Criteria are POJOs.

How to call the methods from android device? How to turn it into web service? Json or XML? REST or SOAP? Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Assumed that you already got some sort of DB with the data for Employee || Criteria stored. Accessing SQL DB from within Android is probably possible but I would assume that you need some drivers for the db. My pick would be to call a server side script that accesses the DB and returns the requested table as JSON.

Android call server Async with Volley request

Assumes you're using GSON and Volley in Android
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

import org.json.JSONObject;

/**
 * Created by Henrik Ekelin on 08/14/2017.
 */
public class ServerRequest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private final static String TAG = ServerRequest.class.getSimpleName();
    private final static String API_URL = "URL/fetchJSON.php";

    private ServerMsgCallback callback;

    public interface ServerMsgCallback {
        void onRetrieved(Employee model);

        void onError(String error);
    }

    public gay(ServerMsgCallback callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
        execute();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(API_URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse() " + response.toString());

                Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
                // Retrieve the fetched JSON as Employee POJO
                Employee employee = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), Employee .class)
                callback.onRetrieved(gson.fromJson(response.toString(), Employee.class));

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onErrorResponse() " + error.getMessage());
                callback.onError(error.getMessage());

            }
        });

        // Add the JSONObject to App Volley RequestQuew
        App.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);

        return null;
    }

}
```

PHP script connecting to SQL server

```
$db = null;
// Connect to database.
try {
    $db = new pdo ('mysql:host=127.0.0.1:3306;dbname=DATABASE_NAME', 'USER', 'PASSWORD');
} catch (PDOException $ex) {
    // Die with mercy
    die (json_encode(array(
        'outcome' => false,
        'message' => 'Unable to connect'
    )));
}

if ($db != null) {

    // Retrieve the _POST msg from client as array
    // {key -> value]
    if (array_key_exists('msg', $_POST)) {
        $data = json_decode($_POST ['msg'], true);

        // Set the value from key 'id'
        $id = $data ['id'];

        // SQL statement retrieving the correct table with ID -> $id
        // Prepare SQL statement
        $s = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE ID = :id');
        // Bind the parameter :name
        $s->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        // Execute
        $s->execute();
        // Fetch the result
        $r = $s->fetchAll();

        // Loop through the result
        foreach ($r as $res) {

            // Find the correct Emplyee with id
            if ($res ['ID'] == $id) {

                // Retrieve the table params and store them as an array
                $arr = array('ID', $res['ID'], 'NAME', $res['NAME'], 'SOMETHING', $res['SOMETHING'], 'BADABING', $res['BADABING']);

                    // Echo the result ie: return JSON
                echo json_encode(array("Employee" => $arr));
            }
        }

    }

}

$db = null;
header('Name: ' . "/location/file.php");
```

Good Luck!

Comment: On server it says **Java** but still u have added php script.

Comment: Doesn't matter just put a fetchJSON.php file on ther server and call it from Android and voila! the content is returned from the call

Comment: How Java server can run php file ? You have some knowledge or just putted answer to get votes ?